# Database first approach and property definitions inside of a model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, database-design, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get a grasp on one project and here is the question. So, when we use a database-first approach - meaning we define the tables in SQL server management studio and then we scaffold this inside of our application in Visual Studio, how can it happen that the generated model class of a particular table contains not only the properties matching the table columns, but also some virtual properties from other tables? For instance, if we have a table with a column AspNetUserId, the model class is going to have the AspNetUserId property, but also a property of type AspNetUsers. How are these additions and "connections" between different tables made like this? And in general I have noticed the following pattern in model classes when comparing with how the tables are defined - if we have for instance Table Document and Table Submission and in Table Submission we have a column ApplicationDocumentId, the model class Submission is going to contain a virtual property of type Document named ApplicationDocument. Is this something Entity Framework does? Can you please give a bit of background on this? Thank you.

Comment: [Reverse Engineering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding) might be a good place to start, and I think [Shadow and Indexer Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) answers a lot of your questions.

Comment: In EF there are many inferred things, one of which is that if there is a column in table A called XXXId , which is a foreign key to table XXX, then it will create a property in entity class A with a property of XXX.

Comment: I think you would better take a look at this link, to learn how it works [EF virtual and relation](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/entity-framework-core/ef-core-relationships-navigation-properties/)